# How to plot NSDate along X axis using Core plot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, graph, nsdate, core-plot

I have tried going through all the examples in core plot, esp dateplot example, but still i am stuck in implementing the plot with hours along the x- axis. Please help me find out where i am going wrong.

Problems I am facing:

- Not able to get the axis with hours distributed evenly (hourly basis, 0900, 1000,....)
- When i am storing it into the plotData array , and when the graph is drawn, all the x values are 0. i mean, all the values are plotted on the y axis only. The x values are not stored.

The code is as follows:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];
 NSTimeInterval oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60;
 NSTimeInterval xLow = 0.0f;

//This part is used to set up the plot space.
CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction=YES;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(xLow)
                                                 length:CPDecimalFromFloat(oneDay)];


    CPXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
CPXYAxis *x=axisSet.xAxis;
x.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromFloat(1*60*60);
x.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
x.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
x.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
//x.visibleRange=xAxisRange;

CPTimeFormatter *timeFormatter = [[[CPTimeFormatter alloc]
                                   initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter1] autorelease];
 Chirp *retValue=[someTemp objectAtIndex:0];
NSDate *tempDate=retValue.startingAt;
timeFormatter.referenceDate = tempDate;
x.labelFormatter = timeFormatter;
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal=CPDecimalFromString(@"0");


  NSMutableArray *newData = [NSMutableArray array];
NSUInteger i;
for ( i = 0; i < [someTemp count]; i++ ) 
{
    Chirp *retValue=[[Chirp alloc]init];
    retValue=[someTemp objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDate *tempDate=retValue.startingAt;
    NSString *dateFromString=[dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:tempDate];
    NSLog(@"%@", dateFromString);
    id x=dateFromString;
    id y=[NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:[retValue.chipCount floatValue]];
    [newData addObject:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      x, [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPScatterPlotFieldX], 
      y, [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPScatterPlotFieldY], 
      nil]];
}
plotData = newData;


-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot
{
return plotData.count;
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
{
NSDecimalNumber *num = [[plotData objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:fieldEnum]];
return num;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create custom labels for the x-axis. see core-plot's bar chart sample. It has custom labels. that way you can show hour,date or anything else you want.

Comment: I will try using the custom labels. But i am also facing the problem of  storing the X values. All my values in the graph are plotted on the y axis, which means, the array is storing all the X values, to be zero. Can u please help me find out where i am going wrong.

Comment: @jeevangs the code you posted above missing plot range for y axis. Try to debug your code and also compare your code with the sample application. you just need to copy and paste sample code in your app and modify the code as per your requirements. Hope this helps

Comment: I didn't post the code for the y axis purposely, as it was working fine, and didnt want to put it up here.

Comment: The custom label on x axis is working perfectly fine. And i tried to figure out my own logic to store the time on x axis as decimal value and store it in the array. Thanks a lot..!

Answer (score 3):

Never mind...! I found the solution to the qn. I had made my x axis use custom labels ( as suggested by Rahul Vyas) . This solved by one of the problem i was facing. And for the other problem, I tried to get the string from NSDate using NSDateformatter and from the string. I am posting the code below. Hope it helps some one.
The code for having custom labels with time on x axis, which is already there in bar chart example.

```
-(void)configureXAxisForGraph:(CPXYGraph*)graphForAxis
{
 CPXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
 CPXYAxis *x=axisSet.xAxis;
 x.majorIntervalLength = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1"] decimalValue];
 CPPlotRange *xAxisRange=[CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromString(@"0.0") length:CPDecimalFromString(@"24.0")];
 x.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
 x.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
 x.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
 x.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
 x.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
 x.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
 x.visibleRange=xAxisRange;
 x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal=CPDecimalFromString(@"0");
 x.title=@"Hours";
 x.titleOffset=47.0f;
 x.labelRotation=M_PI/4;
 x.labelingPolicy=CPAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
 NSArray *customTickLocations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:3], [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:6], [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:9], [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:12], 
                                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:15], [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:18], [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:21], [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:24],nil];
 NSArray *xAxisLabels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"3 AM", @"6 AM", @"9 AM", @"12PM", @"3 PM",@"6 PM",@"9 PM", @"12 AM", nil];
 NSUInteger labelLocation = 0;
 NSMutableArray *customLabels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[xAxisLabels count]];
 for (NSNumber *tickLocation in customTickLocations) 
 {
    CPAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPAxisLabel alloc] initWithText: [xAxisLabels objectAtIndex:labelLocation++] textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
    newLabel.tickLocation = [tickLocation decimalValue];
    newLabel.offset = x.labelOffset + x.majorTickLength;
    newLabel.rotation = M_PI/4;
    [customLabels addObject:newLabel];
    [newLabel release];
}
 x.axisLabels =  [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels];
}
```

Here is the code that worked for me to plot values against number and time(hour).

```
self.dataToBePlotted = [NSMutableArray array];
NSUInteger i;
for ( i = 0; i < [dummyDataArray count]; i++ ) 
{
    Chirp *retValue=[[Chirp alloc]init];
    retValue=[dummyDataArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDate *tempDate=retValue.startingAt;
    NSString *dateFromString=[dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:tempDate];
    NSLog(@"%@", dateFromString);
    id x=dateFromString;
    id y=[NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:[retValue.chipCount floatValue]];
    [self.dataToBePlotted addObject:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      x, [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPScatterPlotFieldX], 
      y, [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPScatterPlotFieldY], 
      nil]];
}
self.plotData = self.dataToBePlotted;


 -(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot
 {  
   return [plotData count];
 } 

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
{
  NSDecimalNumber *num = [[plotData objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:fieldEnum]];
  return num;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your code, i have que: are you only working for hour not for minute, right? is it possible to take hour and minute on xaxis or date and time together for xaxis to plot line chart

Comment: i want to implement line chart y value contains number and for x axis still i am not sure but may be following 1. time with hour, 2.time with hour+minute 3. only date, still i am not sure what core plot support for....can you advice me which one will be supported by core plot

Comment: @Pooja: It generally depends on what value you want to store in the array from where the graph is drawn. In my case, I stored the time stamp value and I can get it down to the milli second along with the date and time. And while displaying with custom labels, I just had to show what I wanted to.

Comment: Can you share this success example to me?? because i am having the same PROBLEM!! please!!!!